# Troubles to configure my IIS server

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-11

I made up a web application for a customer, and I would need your help as my application has some huge troubles to run correctly on client machines with the Internet explorer 11 browser.

This is how my web application is shown by running it on the web server (it's the identification page) :

[image]

And this is how my web application is shown on a client machine :

[image]

The IIS server has only 1 web application installed, the application uses the defaultAppPool authentication to tun, a technician of my customer said the windows user defined for the identification has full rights on the folder of the web application. 
Do you have any idea of what I have to do to solve my problem? I already added the url of the application into the trusted sites list and nothing changed. One last thing, the client machines are on 2 different domains.

PS: I used Webdev 22 to make my web application.

Comment: You are using an external CDN for a css file aren't you? Maybe one related to material design? WIlling to bet that their firewall has it blocked.

Comment: If you use Webdev 22, ask their support resources. Browser compatibility is not easy to troubleshoot if you do lack the experience.

Comment: @LexLi : unfortunately, their support is not able to provide some help to IIS configurations but only on codes, I even asked if there were some advices on the deployment, they said there weren't.

Comment: @TravisActon I'm not using an external CDN, the web application is installed on their local web server

Comment: You don't need them to provide help on IIS configuration. They just need to help you on browser side debugging to learn what exactly breaks the rendering (JavaScript and CSS related). Only when you are 100% clear of the culprit, you can then decide how to fix it. So far based on the description, the culprit is not yet found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a technician at my customer finally found the solution.
Open Internet explorer 11, Tools --> Compatibility View settings, in the pop-up, uncheck **Display intranet sites in Compatibility View**